Id Card Reader is not adding the texts in their labels
So, I am working on an id reader app using python and kivy and opencv and easyocr, the reads is nice but I want to put the reads in their label like the name in the name label and the national id number in the national id number label and the street address in the address label but its not working to me
im beginner and i want a solve to this problemso this is the app interfaceand this is the id card that i want to read it correctly
and this is the python code:
import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
import arabic_reshaper
import bidi.algorithm
import easyocr

Window.size = (375, 600)
Window.clearcolor = (19/255, 41/255, 61/255, 1)

LabelBase.register(name='Arabic', fn_regular='Hacen-Liner-Print-out.ttf')

class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = None
        self.fps = 30
        self._clock_event = None

    def start(self, capture, fps):
        self.capture = capture
        self.fps = fps
        if self._clock_event is None:
            self._clock_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / self.fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.capture is None:
            return
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = frame.tobytes()
            texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            self.texture = texture
            self.frame = frame
        else:
            print('Unable to capture frame.')

class IdCameraWindow(BoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty("Name: ")
    national_id = StringProperty("National Id Number: ")
    address = StringProperty("Address: ")

class IdApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not self.capture.isOpened():
            print('Unable to open camera.')
        self.title = 'ID Camera'
        self.root_widget = IdCameraWindow()
        return self.root_widget

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.my_camera.start(self.capture, 30)

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()

    def extract_text(self):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if not ret:
            print('Unable to capture frame.')
            return
        
        reader = easyocr.Reader(['en', 'ar'], gpu=False)
        result = reader.readtext(frame)
        
        print("OCR Results:")
        for idx, res in enumerate(result):
            print(f"Index {idx}: {res}")
        
        try:
            
            name_part1 = result[2][1]  
            name_part2 = result[3][1]  

           
            full_name = f"{name_part1} {name_part2}"
            
            
            national_id = result[5][1]  

            
            address_full = result[4][1]  
            address_parts = address_full.split()
            filtered_address = " ".join(address_parts[:3])  

           
            reshaped_name = arabic_reshaper.reshape(full_name)
            bidi_name = bidi.algorithm.get_display(reshaped_name)

            reshaped_national_id = arabic_reshaper.reshape(national_id)
            bidi_national_id = bidi.algorithm.get_display(reshaped_national_id)

            reshaped_address = arabic_reshaper.reshape(filtered_address)
            bidi_address = bidi.algorithm.get_display(reshaped_address)

            
            self.root_widget.name = f"Name: {bidi_name}"
            self.root_widget.national_id = f"National Id Number: {bidi_national_id}"
            self.root_widget.address = f"Address: {bidi_address}"
        except IndexError:
            print("OCR result indices are out of range. Please check the OCR output and adjust the indices accordingly.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    IdApp().run()


and this is the .kv file:
<IdCameraWindow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
    KivyCamera:
        id: my_camera
    BoxLayout:
        id: INPUT_BOX
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        Label:
            id: name
            text: root.name
            font_name: "arial"
            background_color: (1,1,1,1)
            size_hint_y: None 
            height: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        Label:
            id: nat_no
            text: root.national_id
            background_color: (1,1,1,1)
            size_hint_y: None
            font_name: "arial"
            height: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        Label:
            id: address
            text: root.address
            background_color: (1,1,1,1)
            font_name: 'arial'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 80
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
    Button:
        text: 'Extract Text'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 80
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_press: app.extract_text()
        color: 42/255, 98/255, 143/255, 1
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
    
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (42/255, 98/255, 143/255, 1)
            Line:
                width: 2
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height


i numbered it like the name is the index number 2 and the fam name is the index number 3 and the street address name is the index number 4 and the national id number is the index number 7
so i was trying to implement this like what i said but its not working for me it adds the address in the national id label and etc..

Is it correctly assigned to indexes in the print output? If not, the whole kivy stuff is unnecessary for the question.

its not assigned in indexes it appears in the output like index 1 ******* index 2 ******* inedx 3 ******** etc.. i want to assign the text in their labels

Try putting your print statements immediately before you assign the text to the properties to see if there is any problem there.
